# eigenvector matrix of non-central Wishart matrix

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I found that the eigenvector matrix of any central Wishart matrix follows Haar distribution, but I cound not find the case for non-central Wishart matrix. Is there any study results about this topic?